# What can be said about $\gcd(N/q^{\alpha},\sigma(N/q^{\alpha}))$ where $N$ is an odd perfect number and $q^{\alpha} \parallel N$?

Tags: computational-number-theory, divisors-multiples, perfect-numbers

What can be said about the quantity $$\gcd(N/q^{\alpha},\sigma(N/q^{\alpha}))$$ where $N$ is an odd perfect number and $q^{\alpha} \parallel N$? In particular, can one prove that it is always greater than one?

Note that, when $q = p$ is the *special prime* of $N$, then since we can express $N$ as $$N = p^k m^2$$ (where $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$), we obtain
$$\gcd(N/q^{\alpha},\sigma(N/q^{\alpha})) = \gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2)) = \sigma(m^2)/p^k = \sigma(N/q^{\alpha})/q^{\alpha},$$
which is always greater than one.

The situation is much more complicated when $q \neq p$.

Comment: You have $\sigma(n/p^\alpha)=\frac{2n}{p^{\alpha}+p^{\alpha-1}+\cdots+1}$, so the gcd is $\frac{n}{p^\alpha (p^\alpha + \cdots + 1)}$, or twice that if $\alpha$ is odd

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @CommandMaster. I think that should be
$$\sigma(n/p^{\alpha})=\frac{2n p^{\alpha} (p - 1)}{p^{\alpha + 1} - 1},$$
if I am not mistaken?

Comment: $n/{p^\alpha}$ and $p^\alpha$ are coprime, so $\sigma(n/{p^\alpha})\sigma(p^\alpha)=\sigma(n)=2n$, so $\sigma(n/{p^\alpha}) = \frac{2n}{\sigma(p^\alpha)} = \frac{2n}{p^\alpha + p^{\alpha-1} + \cdots + 1}$

Comment: @CommandMaster: So are you saying that
$$\gcd(N/q^{\alpha},\sigma(N/q^{\alpha}))={\begin{cases}{\frac{N}{q^{\alpha} \sigma(q^{\alpha})}, \alpha \equiv 0 \pmod 2 \\ \frac{2N}{q^{\alpha} \sigma(q^{\alpha})}, \alpha \equiv 1 \pmod 2}\end{cases}}$$

Comment: Ahh yes, now I agree to your [last comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457769/what-can-be-said-about-gcdn-q-alpha-sigman-q-alpha-where-n-is-an?noredirect=1#comment1185751_457769).

Comment: Ohh, so now I can answer my own question. Thanks again, @CommandMaster! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457769/what-can-be-said-about-gcdn-q-alpha-sigman-q-alpha-where-n-is-an?noredirect=1#comment1185752_457769):

> $$\gcd(N/q^\alpha,\sigma(N/q^\alpha)) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{N}{q^\alpha \sigma(q^\alpha)}, & \alpha \equiv 0 \pmod 2, \\[8pt] \dfrac{2N}{q^\alpha \sigma(q^\alpha)}, & \alpha \equiv 1 \pmod 2. \end{cases}$$

Since it is known that the index
$$\sigma(N/q^{\alpha})/q^{\alpha} \geq 3$$
and since
$$\sigma(q^{\alpha})\sigma(N/q^{\alpha})=\sigma(N)=2N,$$
because $N$ is perfect and $\gcd(q^{\alpha},N/q^{\alpha})=1$, then we obtain
$$\sigma(N/q^{\alpha})/q^{\alpha} = \frac{2N}{q^{\alpha} \sigma(q^{\alpha})}.$$

It follows that

> $$\gcd(N/q^{\alpha},\sigma(N/q^{\alpha})) \geq \dfrac{3}{2} > 1,$$

which proves the original claim.